# Difference in Difference analysis via emmeans in R

Tags: r, emmeans

Using emmeans, I have already coded for the difference and significance in means between: White Christian (WC) Men and Black Christian (BC) men, and then White Muslim (WM) men and Black Muslim (BM) men, for a certain stereotype Dimension. Here is my code for it:

`pairwise_emm2 <- emmeans(fitdata3, pairwise ~ Religion * Race | Dimension, type = "response") pairwise_emm2$contrasts` 
I now want to code for the *differences between these differences*. Meaning I want to know if the WC-BC difference is greater than the WM-BM difference, and if it is significant. Can someone please help me figure out the code for that? Thank you!

Comment: This usually would involve bootstrapping where you estimate your outcome metric e.g. 1000 times based on different sub samples of your data. So I suggest you you could search a bit in that direction (bootstrapping in R).

Comment: This might be a better fit for [stats.se] since you seem to be seeking statistical advice for how to model this particular parameter. Otherwise you should provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output here if this is really just a programming question.